# get row names from sns.heatmap with yticklabels = "auto"

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, seaborn, heatmap

I have a pandas data frame with 399 rows that I'm making a heat map with and am using the yticklabels = 'auto' feature.

When I use the `get_yticklabels()` option:

```
sns.heatmap(df, ax = ax, robust = True, yticklabels = "auto").get_yticklabels()
```

This returns
`<a list of 157 Text yticklabel objects>`.

I tried iterating through the list but I'm just getting objects of class `<class 'matplotlib.text.Text'>` where an entry will be like `Text(0, 0.5, 'hello')`. I'm unable to access that data within this object to pull the string `hello`. 
**Is there a way to do this?**

**How can I get a list of the rows used in the heat map instead of the object?**
My goal is to just pull the rows of the data frame that were in the seaborn heat map for further downstream analysis. that's why I need a list of these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
labels = [t.get_text() for t in ax.get_yticklabels()]
```

will be a list of strings of the y-axis' ticklabels.

Comment: when I do this I get a string like